# String Method Likes "characters.count " not working after some Accessing BLE

Tags: ios, swift3

I a facing a very strange issue regarding calling the string methods.

I have a view Controller in which  i am accessing/sending/receiving information via blue tooth "Default CoreBlueTooth API"

so Initially on page Load my String Methods and properties like Characters.count and Methods like replace are working .

but once the blue tooth scanning procedure starts (specially when i do read), my string methods stop working and the same behavior transfers to all application.

the error which is receive is :

Source Code:

```
          let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(4)
          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime, execute:     {

        let getMacIdHex = "a7".lowercased();
         // String Charactor count works here 
         print("Item test:",self.testString.characters.count);
        self.writeValueChar(data: getMacIdHex) { (callback) in
            print(callback);
            self.logTextView.text = self.logTextView.text + "\n" + "value A7 Get Device UID";
            print("Item test:",self.testString.characters.count);
             //  but String Charactor count doesnt works here ,its in call back
            self.readValueChar { (command, code, xml) in
                //
                 print("Item test:",self.testString.characters.count);
                self.logTextView.text = self.logTextView.text + "\n" + "Mac returned " + command + "\n" + code + "\n" + xml
                print(command, code, xml);

                let macAddress = xml.replacingOccurrences(of: "0000_", with: "")

                //self.lblMacId.text = "MAC address : " + macAddress;
                self.theMacAddress = macAddress;
                completion(true);
                //self.tableView.reloadData();
                //UtilityHelper.HideLoader();

            }


        }
    })
}
```

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x345f3030303000a7).

I am 90% sure , the Error comes from ble read Function:

```
      func readValueChar(completion: @escaping (_ commandNumber: String, _ signalBit: String, _ xmlStr: String) -> Void){
    if(writableCharacteristic != nil){

        peripheral.readValue(for: writableCharacteristic!);
        //print(writableCharacteristic);


        let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)
       RunbackgroundThread(delay:2, completion:{
        // DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime, execute: {

            self.peripheral.readValue(for: self.writableCharacteristic!);
            //print(self.writableCharacteristic);

            let data = self.writableCharacteristic?.value;
            var byteArray: [UInt8] = [];
            data?.copyBytes(to: &byteArray, count: (data?.count)!);

            let commandNumber = String(format:"%2X", (data?[0])!);
            let signalBit = String(format:"%2X", (data?[1])!);

            var xmlStr:String = ""
            if((data?.count)! >= 2){

                var test2 = data?[2..<(data?.count)!]
                xmlStr = String(bytes: test2!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                //print(xmlStr)

            }

            completion(commandNumber, signalBit, xmlStr);

        })





    }
}
```

Can any one explain this behavior and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show some code where it happens?

Comment: You are likely overflowing the very limited Bluetooth LE buffer.  Post code.

Comment: Hello guys Larme and @josh-homann I have updated my Question with code.